# How to get current username in switch case statement

Tags: c#

I want to remove hard code value from case statement.Right now I am giving some hard code values for different users like

```
 ScheduledUtility.ClsISession.OpenSession();
            switch (Convert.ToString(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name))
            {
                case @"suniln":

                    AP.ClsBatchInvoice objBatchInvoice = new AP.ClsBatchInvoice(ScheduledUtility.ClsISession.mySession);
                    objBatchInvoice.ReportId = new Guid("6D783F3C-206C-6576-7273-696F6E3D2231");
                    objBatchInvoice.PDFFileName = "BatchInvoice";
                    objBatchInvoice.VBatchInvoice();
  break;


                case @"vijayk":

                    VendorInvoice_svc objvendor = new VendorInvoice_svc(objsession.mySession);
                    objvendor.GetVenderReports();
                    AP.Aging_svc objaging = new AP.Aging_svc(ScheduledUtility.ClsISession.mySession);
                    objaging.viewerRptAging_Load();
break;
```

How can I write case values and get it from `environment.username`?

Comment: How does this relate to SQL Server? I'm not seeing any SQL related code here.

Comment: May I suggest that you reconsider your approach and look at the [Strategy pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy), with one strategy per role? That will avoid the case statement entirely.

Answer (score 2):

The "case" only accepts constant values so putting the dynamic stuff like variables won't be possible.

P.S. - You better change your approach and associate users with predefined roles put them in constant like Enum and make your decision tree based on predefined roles in switch case.